# How do I highlight particular authors in a bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to indicate one or more authors in a bibliography entry that should be highlighted, e.g., boldface. [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49992/10628) allows one to indicate *one* author from the list, using an index provided in the auxiliary field `usera`.

How would the solution be changed in order to allow multiple authors, e.g.,

```
author = {J. Doe and J. Smith and J. Quincy}
usera = {1,3}
```

This would result in the first and third authors being highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the `usera` field using `\docsvfield`. Here is a simplified macro from the linked solution that will set all author names indicated by `usera` in italics.

```
\newbibmacro*{name:emph}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}} and not test {\iffieldundef{usera}} }
    {\def\do##1{%
       \ifnumequal{##1}{\value{listcount}}{\itshape\listbreak}{}}%
     \docsvfield{usera}}
    {}}
```