# How to emphasize some author names using BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, emphasis

I would like to create bibliographies that have certain authors highlighted (e.g., bold). There are several solutions along these lines, but they usually assume that it's the same author that's being highlight throughout:

- A [biblatex solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)
- A [BibTeX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography)

I'm hoping for a BibTeX solution along [these lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73211/how-do-i-highlight-particular-authors-in-a-bibliography) that lets me indicate, in the `.bib` file, which authors should be highlighted, e.g.,

```
author = {J. Doe and J. Smith and J. Quincy}
usera = {1,3}
```

My goal is to use this for my CV, and to highlight student authors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution works by hacking the bibliography style, similar to what @Katuyci proposed, but conforming more to your example.

1. Make a copy of your style file. I use `plain.bst` here, but it works with any other style, too.
2. Insert `usera` to the `ENTRY` field:

   ```
   ENTRY {
     ...
     year
     usera      %% added
   }
   ```
3. Add the following functions to your style file, after `FUNCTION {not}` (or after `FUNCTION {or} if using natbib). The`mult`and`str.to.int` functions are taken from [Tame the Beast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), with a small bug fix.

   ```
   INTEGERS {length i a b}
   STRINGS {chr}

   FUNCTION {mult}
   {'a :=                  %% we store the first value
    'b :=                  %% we store the second value
    b #0 <                 %% We remember the sign of b, and
       {#-1 #0 b - 'b :=} %% then consider its absolute value.
       {#1}               %%
   if$                    %%
   #0                     %% Put 0 on the stack.
   {b #0 >}               %% While b is strictly positive,
   {                      %% we add a to the value on the stack
       a +                 %% and decrement b.
       b #1 - 'b :=        %%
   }                      %%
   while$                 %%
   swap$                  %% Last, we take the opposite
       'skip$              %% if b was negative.
       {#0 swap$ -}        %%
   if$                    %%
   }

   FUNCTION {chr.to.value}        %% The ASCII code of a character
   {
   chr.to.int$ #48 -            %% ASCII value of "0" -> 48
   duplicate$ duplicate$        %%                "1" -> 49
   #0 < swap$ #9 > or           %%                   ...
   {                            %%                "9" -> 57
       #48 + int.to.chr$
       " is not a number..." *
       warning$                %% Return 0 if it is not a number
       #0                      %% here we removed the pop$ before #0,
                               %% opposed to what is written in Tame The Beast
       }
   {}
   if$
   }
   FUNCTION {str.to.int.aux}      %% The auxiliary function
   {
   {duplicate$ empty$ not}      %% While the string is not empty
       {                         %% consider its first char
       swap$ #10 mult 'a :=    %% and ‘‘add’’ it at the end of
       duplicate$ #1 #1 substring$   %% the result.
       chr.to.value a +
       swap$
       #2 global.max$ substring$
       }
   while$
   pop$
   }
   FUNCTION {str.to.int}
   {                              %% Handling negative values
   duplicate$ #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
       {#1 swap$ #2 global.max$ substring$}  %% the first integer here indicates whether we have to
                                           %% multiply by -1, i.e., it is consumed by the following if$
       {#0 swap$}
   if$
                               %% Initialization, and then
   #0 swap$ str.to.int.aux      %% call to the aux. funtion
   swap$
       {#0 swap$ -}              %% And handle the sign.
       {}
   if$
   }

   %% takes a string literal from the stack and returns
   %% the position of the first " " (space) in the string;
   %% returns -1 if no space is contained
   FUNCTION {first.space}{
   duplicate$ text.length$ #1 + 'length :=
   #1 'i :=
   { 
       i length <
       { duplicate$ i #1 substring$ 'chr :=
         chr " " =
           { #0 }
           { #1 }
         if$
       }
       {
         #-1
       }
       if$
   }
   { #1 i + 'i := }
   while$
   i length =
       {
         #-1 'i :=
       }
       {}
   if$
   %% finally take the string from the stack
   pop$
   %% space position we identified
   i
   }

   %% takes a string literal from the stack,
   %% and returns the first number in the string, and the remaining string;
   %% returns -1 and the original string if no number is found
   STRINGS { tmpstr }
   FUNCTION {chop.number} {
   'tmpstr :=
   tmpstr first.space 'i :=
   i #0 >
       { tmpstr i #1 + global.max$ substring$ %% remaining string
         tmpstr #1 i #1 - substring$ str.to.int    %% number
         duplicate$ #0 =
           { pop$ #-1 }
           {}
         if$
       }
       { "" tmpstr str.to.int
         duplicate$ #0 =
           { pop$ #-1 }
           {}
         if$
       }
   if$
   }
   ```
4. Now locate `FUNCTION {format.names}`, and put

   ```
   INTEGERS { hlauthor hlauthorold }
   STRINGS { hlstr }
   ```

   before that.
5. `format.names` has to be modified. I indicated all lines that I added. Your function might look a little different when you are not working with `plain.bst`, but pretty similar.

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.names}
   { 
   's :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
   usera 'hlstr :=                                          %% added
   hlstr chop.number 'hlauthor := 'hlstr :=                 %% added
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
       nameptr hlauthor =                                   %% added
         {                                                  %% added
           "\hlauthor{" t * "}" * 't :=                     %% added
           hlauthor 'hlauthorold :=                         %% added
           hlstr chop.number 'hlauthor := 'hlstr :=         %% added
           hlauthor #0 >                                    %% added
             { hlauthor hlauthorold >                       %% added
                 {}                                         %% added
                 { "Highlighted authors not sorted for "    %% added
                   cite$ * ": " * hlauthorold int.to.str$ * %% added
                   " >= " * hlauthor int.to.str$ * warning$ %% added
                 }                                          %% added
               if$                                          %% added
             }                                              %% added
             {}                                             %% added
           if$                                              %% added
         }                                                  %% added
         {}                                                 %% added
       if$                                                  %% added
       nameptr #1 >
           { namesleft #1 >
               { ", " * t * }
               { numnames #2 >
                   { "," * }
                   'skip$
               if$
               t "others" =
                   { " et~al." * }
                   { " and " * t * }
               if$
               }
           if$
           }
           't
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
       }
   while$
   %% Sanity checks: hlstr should be empty,                 %% added
   %% and hlauthor should be -1                             %% added
   hlstr "" =                                               %% added
     {}                                                     %% added
     { "There are remaining authors to be highlighted for " %% added
       cite$ * ": " * hlstr * warning$                      %% added
     }                                                      %% added
   if$                                                      %% added
   hlauthor #-1 =                                           %% added
     {}                                                     %% added
     { "Unable to highlight author number " hlauthor        %% added
       int.to.str$ * " for " * cite$ * warning$             %% added
     }                                                      %% added
   if$                                                      %% added
   }
   ```
6. Finally, we provide a default style for highlighting authors, here we use bold. This is to be injected into the `begin.bib` function:

   ```
   FUNCTION {begin.bib}
   { preamble$ empty$
       'skip$
       { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
     if$
     "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
     "\providecommand*{\hlauthor}[1]{\textbf{#1}}" write$ newline$   %% added
   }
   ```

That's it! Let's test it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{hltest.bib}
@book{a,
  author = {A. First and B. Second and C. Third and D. Forth and E. Fifth and F. Sixth and G. Seventh},
  usera = {1 3 5 4},
  title = {My book title},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {Inhouse}
}

@book{b,
  author = {A. One and B. Two and C. Three},
  usera = {1 4},
  title = {My book title},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {Inhouse}
}

@book{c,
  author = {A. Uno and B. Due and C. Tre},
  usera = {4 5},
  title = {My book title},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {Inhouse}
}

@book{d,
  author = {A. Eins and B. Zwei and C. Drei},
  usera = { 2},
  title = {My book title},
  year = 2013,
  publisher = {Inhouse}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

% \providecommand{\hlauthor}[1]{\emph{#1}} % if you want to change the style of emphasis
\bibliographystyle{hlplain}
\bibliography{hltest}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Note that authors to be emphasized should be given in increasing order, e.g.

```
usera = {10 13 15}, OK
usera = {9 1 2},    NOT OK
```

separated by spaces. Otherwise you will get warnings as in the test code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an application of the `l3regex` package, combined with a [previous idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18668/4427)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
 author={Studenta A. and Foo B.},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
@article{b,
 author={Studentb A. and Studentc B.},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
@article{c,
 author={Foo B. and Baz  B.},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_new:N \g_hl_students_regex
\seq_new:N \l_hl_students_seq
\tl_new:N \l_hl_data_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\studentslist}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_hl_students_seq { , } { #1 }
  \regex_gset:Nx \g_hl_students_regex
   { ( \seq_use:Nnnn \l_hl_students_seq { | } { | } { | } ) }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_gset:Nn { Nx }

\cs_set_eq:NN \hl_bibitem:w \bibitem
\cs_set:Npn \bibitem #1#2\par
 {
  \hl_bibitem:w { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_hl_data_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:NnN \g_hl_students_regex { \c{emph}\cB\{ \1 \cE\} } \l_hl_data_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_hl_data_tl \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\studentslist{Studenta, Studentb, Studentc}

\begin{document}
abc
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

As usual, `filecontents*` is used only for making the example self consistent, one can use any `.bib` file.

The comma separated list of students names is given in the preamble.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perphaps you can try the idea of a previous [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91257/underline-different-authors-in-the-bibliography-by-hacking-bst-file/91520#91520). I will suggest some adjustments to your method and how to do it.

Instead of using **numbers** in the *usera = { ...}* field perhaps you can use the **author's name** you want to highlight. I believe it would be as easy as inserting the rank. **Be sure that if you use full names or short names for the *first name* you do the same in *usera***

Declare *usera* in `ENTRY {... usera ...}` and create a new function before `FUNCTION{format.names}` as follows:

```
FUNCTION {student.author}  
{
  usera empty$  
    { "" }  
    { usera nameptr STYLE format.name$ }  
    if$  
}
```

**NOTE** change the above *style* to whatever style your current .bst file uses. You can find, and copy it, in `FUNCTION{format.names}`. Should be something similar to `"{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"`.

Create the function to highlight:

```
FUNCTION {highlight}  
{ duplicate$ empty$  
      { pop$ "" }  
      { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }  
   if$  
}
```

and call this function whenever the author being parsed is your student author:

```
FUNCTION {highlight.if.student.author}  
{ duplicate$ purify$ student.author purify$ =  
    { highlight }  
    'skip$  
  if$  
}
```

Finally, call the `highlight.if.student.author` after `format.name$` in `FUNCTION{format.names)` as follows:

```
FUNCTION{format.names}  
{...  
format.names$ highlight.if.student.author  
...  
}
```

Comment: My solution is handy if there is some entries in your bibliography that don't need to be highlight. If you prefer to have the students name highlighted throughout the CV you may consider adding a list with the names instead of using the `FUNCTION{student.author}`.
In fact, you can set up a way to retrieve those names from the main.tex file where it will be more easy to you to add/update the students' list.