# Underline different authors in the bibliography by hacking BST file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, moderncv

I am updating my CV (`moderncv`) and I am including a list of all my communications (oral and poster) using multibib (I use different `.bib` files for each one).

The final output should display my name in bold and the presenting author underlined.

So far I have figured out how to do the first bit but have not find solution for the last part.
Because the presenting author is not always the same person I was thinking in using the "comment field" to tell BibTeX/LaTex who I want to underline in that specific entry.

Because I do not have enough skills to do that I wonder if anyone can give me a help.

EDITED

I am using a .bst file.

Comment: [Welcome to TX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Do you use a `bst` file, or `biblatex`?

Comment: Note that underlining is not a very nice typographical style; we might use it in hand-written text because we can't do bold or italic, but you might want to try other styles (e.g. italic) and see if they look better than underlining.

Comment: Gerrit, thank you for your comment. I don't mind doing something different to the text, I just want a way to systematically doing so where I only have to say which (presenting) author/name is to be typographically distinct from everything else.

Comment: @gerrit I can hand-write italic :-) I think that you meant typewritten (as with a old fashioned mechanical typewriter) text.

Comment: @gerrit You are right. However, in some fields there is a convention that when a work of multiple people is presented, the name of the speaker is underlined. So for me, despite being "typographically incorrect", it is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: I've noticed that if I include: \textbf or \emph or \underline in  the .bib file for the specific/speaker author, that information will show "almost" correct output BUT some of the author style (or maybe all) will be lost, for instances the use of dots for forenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By following a previous [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography) I was able to fulfill my question when using the **plain.bst** file.

First, I've added a **comment** field in .bib file as a easier way to referrence which was the speaker/presenting author and declared this new field in plain.bst file:

```
ENTRY{  
...  
...  
chapter  
comment  
...  
}
```

Second, I've created a new function (`speaker.author`) to set the name in the same format as this style uses in `format.names`:

```
FUNCTION {speaker.author}  
{
  comment empty$  
    { "" }  
    { comment nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ }  
    if$  
}
```

Third, a new function (`highlight`) is created to highlight a text, in our case a name. In this case I opt to underline the text/name but you can set whatever text style you want.

```
FUNCTION {highlight}  
{ duplicate$ empty$  
      { pop$ "" }  
      { "\underline{" swap$ * "}" * }  
   if$  
}
```

Fourth, a new function (`highlight.if.speaker.author`) is created to run `highlight` if the author on the stack (see next) is the same as `speaker.author`.

```
FUNCTION {highlight.if.speaker.author}  
{ duplicate$ purify$ speaker.author purify$ =  
    { highlight }  
    'skip$  
  if$  
}
```

Last, insert a call to `highlight.if.speaker.author` to `FUNCTION{format.names}` right after the `format.names$`.

```
FUNCTION{format.names}  
{...  
format.names$ highlight.if.speaker.author  
...  
}
```

NOTE: step 2-4 should be placed before `FUNCTION{format.names}`. The only flaw in this method (which arises from the fact that *plain.bst* style does not abbreviate names) is that you have to make sure that the way you type the author name in *author* field is the same as in *comment* because "Doe, John" and "Doe, J" will be seen as different names, although "Doe, J", "Doe, J." or "J Doe" will be seen as equal.

---

EDITED

In some particular cases you may want to have your name in bold together with the previous style (if you are the speaker AND the author of the CV). In that case use the following two new functions:

```
FUNCTION {cv.author}
{ "Doe, John" nameptr  "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}" format.name$ }

FUNCTION{double.highlight}
{ duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "\textbf{\underline{" swap$ * "}}" * }
   if$
}
```

And then, change `FUNCTION{highlight.if.speaker.author}` to this:

```
FUNCTION {highlight.if.speaker.author}
{ duplicate$ purify$ speaker.author purify$ =
        { speaker.author cv.author =
    { double.highlight }
    {highlight}
    if$
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Comment: Just for reference: I made a [similar answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100298/21591) to the other bibtex-author-emphasis question.