# BibLaTeX: Highlight Self-References

Tags: biblatex, citing, highlighting, brackets

I am looking for a way to highlight references to my own previous publications using BibLaTeX (alphabetic cite and bibliography style), for example by using double brackets as citation marks in the text and in the bibliography. It should look the following way:

```
This is a paper published by myself [[MS15]] and that is a paper published
by someone else [AB14].

References:
[[MS15]]    Moser, S., ...., Title, Year.
[AB14]      Author X., ...., Title, Year.
```

I've a working solution using BibTex. Therefore I copied "alphadin.bst" to my LaTeX project folder and added some additional entries for custom bibtex types which are used for my own publications:

```
FUNCTION {output.mybibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{[" write$
  label write$%
  "]}]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$%
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

[...]

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
article.common
}

FUNCTION {myarticle}
{  output.mybibitem
article.common
}
```

This allows me to add custom entries to the Bibtex file (e.g. "myarticle"). They are printed with double brackets both in the cite mark and in the bibliography.

For various reasons I'd like to switch to BibLaTeX and Biber as the backend. Therefore my question: Is there a similar solution or even a much nicer way to accomplish this? I don't necessarily need extra types for "my" publications in the bibliography file. It would be also possible to use, for example, keywords and using the available standard types.

I don't like to have the local, modified copy of "alphadin.bst" of the current BibTex solution at all. So if I could "patch" BibLaTeX's behavior without having a completely redundant style file, it would be great.

Thank you very much in advance for any helpful solutions!

Kind regards,

Steffen

Comment: Probably easiest from a use point of view to filter cases where you are author. But a minimal example document with some `.bib` entries suitable for testing and information about the style you'd be using etc. would be helpful. If you search, there have been a few questions along these lines. (Not doing exactly this but similarly tweaking self-authored sources etc.)

Comment: There are solutions to highlight a particular author ([Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33330/35864), [Underline my name in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18664/35864), [How do I highlight particular authors in a bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73211/35864), [Italicizing an Author in Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49975/35864)) or to filter by author [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864)...

Comment: ... ([biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65114/35864)) From a programming point of view I cannot fully agree with cfr. Filtering by author names is notoriously hard, although `biblatex` offers very good facilities for that now. So if you have a `keyword` that you add to articles (co-)written by you that should be a walk in the park.

Comment: Did you get anywhere? Do you need more pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Using `keyword`s will be very easy from a programming point of view. So you simply add `keyowrds={mywork}` to your entries and use the standard entry types.

```
@Article{Benji,
  author    = {Benji},
  keywords  = {mywork},
}
```

With `numeric` and `numeric-verb` you could use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\ifkeyword{mywork}{[\mkbibbrackets{#1}]}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \ifkeyword{mywork}{[}{}%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifkeyword{mywork}{]}{}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
```

In [a very similar question over at goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,77790.html) the OP uses `style=ieee` which is much harder to get right.
It can be done with [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)

```
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@lastmywork}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite:comp:comp}
  {\savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}
  {\savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}%
   \ifkeyword{mywork}{\toggletrue{cbx@lastmywork}}{\togglefalse{cbx@lastmywork}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite:dump}
  {\printtext{\cbx@lastnumber}}
  {\printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}
  {}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{mywork}} or togl {cbx@lastmywork}}
    {[#1]}
    {#1}}
\makeatother
```

For `numeric-comp` we can drop the patching of `cite:dump`,

```
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@lastmywork}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite:comp:comp}
  {\savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}
  {\savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}%
   \ifkeyword{mywork}{\toggletrue{cbx@lastmywork}}{\togglefalse{cbx@lastmywork}}}
  {}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{mywork}} or togl {cbx@lastmywork}}
    {[#1]}
    {#1}}
\makeatother
```

is enough.

MWE for `numeric`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Einstein,
  author    = {Einstein},
}
@Article{Benji,
  author    = {Benji},
  keywords  = {mywork},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\ifkeyword{mywork}{[\mkbibbrackets{#1}]}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \ifkeyword{mywork}{[}{}%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifkeyword{mywork}{]}{}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\begin{document}
Fremdquelle \cite{Einstein}

Eigenquelle \cite{Benji} and \cite{Benji,Einstein} and \cite{Einstein,Benji}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output with <code>style=numeric</code>]