# Highlight specific authors in the bibliography and citations declaring their names as commands using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, highlighting

I want to be able to define a list of authors in a command and highlight them in the bibliography or citations. I am using **biblatex** with my latex document (I have not been able to update my OS lately and I am using Package: biblatex 2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)).

So far I have been able to create a new macro that is called each time the names of the authors are printed. However, when I compare the author last name and first name with the values that I defined using `\newcommand`, I always get the evaluation to false in the if statement. Here is what I got so far (inspired by a combination of [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49975/italicizing-an-author-in-biblatex/49992#49992)], [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297720/highlight-an-author-in-bibliography-using-biblatex-gost-package)] and [[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49975/italicizing-an-author-in-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1)]) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{boldref, 
  AUTHOR = {InBold, to Put and Author, Non bold  and Highlight, Shine and  Ano, therOne},
  TITLE = {The title},
  BOOKTITLE = {The conference},
  PAGES = {65--78},
  YEAR = 2014}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp,maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\newcommand{\authorgivenname}{t. P.} 
\newcommand{\authorfamilyname}{InBold} 
\newcommand{\authorbibname}{\authorfamilyname, \authorgivenname} 

\newbibmacro*{name:emph}[2]{%
    First arugment: #1 =? \authorfamilyname \\
    Second argument: #2 =? \authorgivenname \\
    \ifstrequal{#2}{\authorgivenname}
    {
        \textcolor{green}{Evaluated to true: #1, #2} \\
    }
    {
        \textcolor{red}{Evaluated to false: #1, #2} \\
    }
}

\xpretobibmacro{name:last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:first-last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}    
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}    

\xapptobibmacro{name:last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:first-last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}    
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{} 


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\noindent\fullcite{boldref}

\end{document}
```

If I get this code to work, the idea is that I will change `\textcolor{green}{Evaluated to true: #1, #2}` to `\bfseries` and the author name will be in bold font. I suspect that this has to do with when each element is expanded. Am I right? How can I fix it? Moreover, how can I extend it to compare with a list of elements rather than just one author?

I also noted that the variables `#1` and `#2` are already processed by some other macro when the macro `name:emph` is called and give the abbreviated name (if it is requested in the configuration of biblatex). This means that I would have to declare different authors names depending on the configuration of `firstinits` option in biblatex.

Thank you very much.

P.S.: I have read other options that add elements to the bibliography entries ([[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49975/italicizing-an-author-in-biblatex/49992#49992)] or [[4](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-biblatex-conveniently-highlight-your-author-mark-coletti-phd)]) but I do not want that as I automatically generate my bibliography files (.bib) with programs that do not support adding fields. I have also tried to build on top of [[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)] but I cannot even get to compile that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. The first is that your code uses the old name format with `first` and `last`, `biblatex` has been using `given` and `family` instead for two years now [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

So you need

```
\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}    
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}    

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}    
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}
```

The second problem is with `\ifstrequal{#2}{\authorgivenname}` in `name:emph`. What you actually need is `\ifdefstrequal`. `\ifstrequal` compares its two arguments as strings directly and does not expand anything. So `\ifstrequal{hallo}{hallo}` is true, but `\def\hallo{hallo}` `\ifstrequal{\hallo}{hallo}` is not true. `\authorgivenname` is already a macro and `#2` will ultimately be the macro `\namepartgiven`, so what we compare two macros here. This is done with `\ifdefstrequal`.

Your third problem is that the first name initials of `InBold, to Put` are not actually `t. P.`, they are `t\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim P\bibinitperiod`.
So

```
\newcommand{\authorgivenname}{t\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim P\bibinitperiod}
```

works. Alternatively, you would have to 'normalise' these commands for the name comparison as shown [in Audrey's answer to *Make specific author bold using biblatex*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/35864).

In full

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{boldref, 
  AUTHOR = {InBold, to Put and Author, Non bold  and Highlight, Shine and  Ano, therOne},
  TITLE = {The title},
  BOOKTITLE = {The conference},
  PAGES = {65--78},
  YEAR = 2014}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp,maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\authorgivenname}{t\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim P\bibinitperiod} 
\newcommand{\authorfamilyname}{InBold} 
\newcommand{\authorbibname}{\authorfamilyname, \authorgivenname} 

\newbibmacro*{name:emph}[2]{%
    First arugment: #1 =? \authorfamilyname \\
    Second argument: #2 =? \authorgivenname \\
    \ifdefstrequal{\authorgivenname}{#2}
    {
        \textcolor{green}{Evaluated to true: #1, #2} \\
    }
    {
        \textcolor{red}{Evaluated to false: #1, #2} \\
    }
}

\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}    
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}    

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}    
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{} 


\begin{document}
\def\hallo{hallo}
\ifstrequal{\hallo}{hallo}{a}{b}

\nocite{*}
\noindent\fullcite{boldref}
\end{document}
```

---

As it turns out your `biblatex` is more than four years old now.
You don't need to worry about the new name format in that case and can stick with

```
\xpretobibmacro{name:last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:first-last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:emph}{#1}{#2}}{}{}    
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}    

\xapptobibmacro{name:last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:first-last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}    
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}
```

In that old version the `#2` in `\ifstrequal{#2}{\authorgivenname}` was not a macro but a string, `\authorgivenname` is still a macro, though, so you should try

```
\ifdefstring{\authorgivenname}{#2}
```

for the comparison.

---

Instead of this solution I would recommend you try [my answer to *Make specific author bold using biblatex*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) instead. The advantage is that you can input a name as you would in the `.bib` file and that the answer responds to `giveninits` automatically.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I will have a look at all this information to see if I solve this. If I do you'll get upvote and accepted. However, I want to point out that I might be using an old version of biblatex as the commands you pointe out that changed (`given-family` instead of `first-last`) do no work for me.

Comment: I confirm that I am using a quite old version: Package: biblatex 2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

Comment: @apalomer Ah, well that is an ancient version. Things are different there. Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864

Comment: Thank you very much. The `\ifdefstring{\authorgivenname}{#2}` was the solution!! Moreover, I think this answer is a very good answer as it gives a lot of options and references to other good answers. I keep this for when I update the biblatex (as I assume it will stop working).